# Mocha test runner with external files - hooks run in different order?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to organise my mocha tests to run through a separate test runner. Whenever I run the test, console.log outputs a proper connection in the top level `before` block, but straight after outputs me null in the separate required file `it` block. The hook is being executed, and it sets the `connection` variable correctly, but somehow it does not get passed to the required file.

How come the connection does not get properly set? Confusingly, according to my debugger `it` block is executed before the `before` hook which contradicts the order of `console.log`s I see

```
describe.only('test-suite', async () => {
    let connection; // undefinded at this point

    before(async () => {
        connection = await getConnection();
        console.log(connection); -> proper connection instance
    });

    after(async () => {
        await closeConnection();
    });

    require('./some/test')(
        connection
    );
});
```

./some/test.js

```
module.exports = async (
    connection,
) => {
    describe('my-method', async () => {
        it('does things', async () => {
            console.log(connection); // somehow undefined
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the way JS handles references to objects. Reassigning the variable does not just change the value the reference points to, but instead creates a brand new reference pointing to a brand new value.

This is the workaround:

```
describe.only('test-suite', async () => {
    let options = { connection: null};

    before(async () => {
        options.connection = await getConnection();
        console.log(connection);
    });

    after(async () => {
        await closeConnection();
    });

    require('./some/test')(
        options
    );
});
```

./some/test.js

```
module.exports = async (
    options,
) => {
    describe('my-method', async () => {
        it('does things', async () => {
            console.log(options.connection);
        });
    });
};
```